# WCF Data Service - JSON response has extra "results" section

Tags: json, wcf-data-services

Using the [WCF Data Services Toolkit](http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com), or the other ways to support the `$format` param such as `JSONPSupportInspectorAttribute` I am getting some json responses that are a little odd to me.

Why does my json look like:

```
{
"d" : {
"results": [
{
"__metadata": {
```

When the json from [OData.org $format](http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?%24format=json) is as follows:

```
{
"d" : [
{
"__metadata": {
```

Why does mine have an extra "results" sub section?

My data service is just built directly onto my entity framework model. Do I have to use a specific context template for this to go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is versioning. In V2 we added the server driven paging and inline count features which need to store additional metadata on the feed. But since the feed in V1 was just a JSON array, there was no place to put such metadata.

So in V2 all feeds in responses are wrapped in "results" wrapper. That is the feed is a JSON object which has a property called "results" which has the array. There might be additional properties on the feed object (next link, count, ...).

The versioning of the payload is based on the minimum version required by any feature in that payload. So if your service is using something which requires payload of version higher than V1, the entire payload will be written using that higher version.

You can see this even on the odata.org service - try this:
http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$inlinecount=allpages&$format=json

The response will be V2 and will use the results wrapper.

Comment: The payload does carry version information with it. DataServiceVersion header is for that purpose. So no guessing necessary. The description above is about the server deciding which version to use to respond to a client request, not about reading an existing payload.

Comment: I am sorry you are right. There is a header signifying versions. I do not know how I have missed it it might be that the proxy server was stripping it off, I don't know. But anyway thanks.

Comment: By the way, IMHO that information should have been implemented as part of `Content-Type` for example: `Content-Type: application/json;DataServiceVersion=2.0`. Also there is a `;` semicolon at the of the version number which is not great.